# Creating a form in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I have created one form in wordpress :

```
 <form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" id="addForm" method="post">
       <input type = "submit" value="Add" name="send">
 </form>
```

On page load I am checking if $_POST[send] is set or not and executing the query accordingly.

This work when all fields are empty in form and a empty record is added to database and page comes back to the form.

But when I enter some values and then submit the form it does not add any thing into database and it show a message :

Nothing Found

Apologies, but no results were found for the requested archive. Perhaps searching will help find a related post.

Comment: are you checking for `$_POST[send]` or `$_POST['send']` ?

Comment: @sircapsalot Generally the quotes don't matter, but `$_POST[$send]` vs `$_POST['send']` does.

Comment: I am checking $_POST['send']

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing  `action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"` to `action=""`

Also for field names avoid using generic words like "name","city" and use more unique ones.

Comment: that worked .. after changing name to cname of form element .. thnxx. :)

Comment: If you found the answer useful, please take a moment and accept it by clicking on the large checkbox on the left side of this answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you've not included code other than the form, I'm making an assumption here but try the following:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['send'])) {
    insert query here
}
?>
```

You mentioned that you're checking if it's set, but not whether you're checking if it's empty. PHP function [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) is better for this because it checks whether the variable is set and then whether it's empty, so two birds, one stone. =)

Comment: tried both action="" and !empty($_POST['send']).. getting same error :(

Comment: Still having the issue? Can you share the entire code and I'll try to help you?

Comment: thnx david prob solved.. i was using form attributes as name = "name" email = "email", may be bcs of them i was getting the error. After changing name = "cname" email="cemail", it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
    insert query here
}
?>
```

And check it again and reply